# Angular 7 trying to create a new line

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a new line in an html in Angular 7, cli 7.3.6.

I trying to create a new line in an html in Angular 7, cli 7.3.6. Right before the html "*" I tried to insert 
 tag but it doesn't work.

```
 <div class="row my-2 ">
            <div class="col-sm-5 pl-3 border border-2" [innerHtml]="tip.tip | safe: 'html'">

            </div>         
        </div>
```

*Drink at least 8 glasses (8 ounces/250mL per glass) of fluids per day. This includes water, juices, soups, Gatorade® diluted in water. *Eat foods like prunes, dates, figs, fresh fruits, vegetables, or bran. *Do more exercise (e.g. walking). *Take any prescription medications for constipation that your doctor has given you. A pharmacist can also help you find and use medications without a prescription, such as laxatives(e.g. Senokot®, Bisacodyl®, Restor-a-lax®, Lax-a-day®) or stool softeners(e.g. Colace®). Follow the directions on the bottle for each medication. *Call your healthcare team if you have any questions about what medications to take.

I expected if I placed a br tag it will skip another line but it doesn't.
[image]

Comment: unclear what you're asking, but why are you doing this? at all instead of using angular's templating system

Comment: The tip.tip is a variable that contains the content. The content is obtain from a web service call.  The client wants the line to be a new line whenever there is a "*".

Answer (score 1):

You may use a pipe to transform your html and insert 
 before * or replace * with < br />. I have attached an example of the pipe here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-break-on-star-pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'breakOnStar'})
export class BreakOnStar implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value.replace(/(?=\*)/g, '<br/>');
  }
}
```

This is how you can use it

```
 <div class="col-sm-5 pl-3 border border-2" [innerHtml]="tip.tip | breakOnStar | safe: 'html'">

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your approach here is off, I'd recommend a safer and more angular approach.

add this in your component somewhere appropriate:

```
this.tipList = this.tip.tip.split(/(?=\*)/g);
```

then simply use the tipList to iterate:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 pl-3 border border-2">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let tip of tipList">
    {{tip}}<br>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

this also gives you far greater control in how you can display and style your list. You can use other html elements as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your component, just add the correct tag

```
//You might need regular expressions if this does not cover all cases
tip.tip = tip.tip.replace('*', '<br/>*');
```

In your template, just use simply property binding

```
<div [innerHtml]="tip.tip"
```